# Moving Sharepoint Server 2019 to Sharepoint in 365 (Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, 2019

We're on Server 2019 and looking to move to Sharepoint in 365 (Online). Looks like the migration tool only supports 2013 and 2016. Is there support coming for that or another way? I see there are a few paid migration tools out there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently SharePoint server 2019 is the Mainstream support for SharePoint on-premise.

So there is no OOB way to migrate SharePoint server 2019 to SharePoint online.

Comment: So is there likely to be no support for moving 2019 until 2019 falls out of Mainstream support?

Comment: The short answer is : yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 3rd part appliucation like, Sharegate or Metalogix

Comment: Agreed. Hoping for a free option but it doesn't look like there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using these tools with 2019? It's most likely that the documentation simply wasn't updated. There's not a huge difference between 2016 and 2019, I'd expect it to work.

Comment: It checks the version when you run it. It says 2019 is not supported and stops.

Comment: That sucks! Thanks for the heads up - will keep in mind when planning migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ShareGate Desktop. You need to use a professional mail.
The trial will hell you to migrate from all kind version of sharepoint to sharepoint online.